# How to increase one hours current date in DEC UNIX 4.0?

Tags: date, unix

I need to add one hours to current date in DEC UNIX V4.0?

I tried "date" command but in this version of that command "-v" or "-s" and etc switch doesn't work.

for example:

```
date -s "5 seconds"
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already read the DEC manual page and observed that there is no option that matches the `-v` or `-s` options in GNU `date`.  From that, you will conclude that you'll have to write your own code or get someone else's already written code to do the job — and you'll conclude that installing someone else's working code is easier than writing your own code.

The simplest fix, therefore, is to install GNU [`coreutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils) and use the `date` command from that.  Of course, there are some tricky bits to deal with.  You'll probably not want to install the GNU `date` command in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` because that might break other scripts that expect the DEC version of the `date` command (it probably won't, but it might, and you're likely to be cautious — if you weren't cautious, you wouldn't still be using DEC UNIX).  So, you probably need to add it to `/usr/local/bin`, or maybe you create a new directory such as `/usr/gnu/bin` (add `--prefix=/usr/gnu` to the `./configure` command when you build the core utilities).  And then you ensure that the commands that need to use GNU `date` reference it explicitly.  (Commands that don't insist on using GNU `date` should continue to use DEC `date`.)